# Some key pressing not intercepted under Linux OS

Tags: linux, keyboard

Some keys on my keyboard (by example wi-fi on/off and webcam on/off) aren't working under a Linux OS, but work well under Windows. So i tried to find a solution searching around the web and everyone suggests to use one of the following commands.

`cat /dev/input/event`
`acpi_listen`
`showkey`
`xev`

Sadly none of these commands catches my key pressing/releasing events. I don't know what it means, however i will really appreciate an explanation or any hint to find a solution.

My hardware is a Clevo W860CU laptop.

Answer (score 1):

["HAL Keymap Quirks"](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-index.html)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still having issues on finding scan codes, this one use `dmesg`, but is better then nothing.